# App Icon Switcher does not work on iPad, only the default icon - Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, assets, ipados, appicon

I am integrating a app icon switcher to one of my apps. It works fine on iOS, but when I run on iPadOS only the default icon works for the other icon -> File not found.

Assets:
icon@2x.png (120px)
icon@3x.png (180px)

```
class IconManager {
    let application = UIApplication.shared
    
    // same naming convention in the plist to reference to actual files
    enum AppIcon: String {
        case iconDark
        case iconDarkSimple
        case iconLight
        case iconLightSimple
    }
   
    func changeAppIcon(to appIcon: AppIcon) {
        application.setAlternateIconName(appIcon.rawValue)
    }
}
```

Does an in app icon switcher even work on iPadOS!?

Answer (score -1):

Please print the error log, the log will tell you what is wrong：

```
setAlternateIconName(_ alternateIconName: String?, completionHandler: ((Error?) -> Void)? = nil)
```

Comment: I did that already, and I wrote it above! Under iPhone everything is working, but on iPad an error: File Not Found is coming up